# Gradle: Is there a better way to assign the same dependency to 2 configurations?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Just a general question but is there a cleaner way to assign the same dependency to 2 configurations?  Right now I have the following code, which works, but would like to clean it up if possible

```
dependencies{
    compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysql_conn_ver}"
    sql "mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysql_conn_ver}"
}
```

As you can see they use the exact same thing so for  now I just call the dependency for the sql configuration inside of the task that uses it.  I'd rather just assign it once if at all possible.  Thank you

Comment: `[compile, sql].each { it( "mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysql_conn_ver}") }` is one way, but there are a few different ways depending on your style. Another option is `extendsFrom`. I think answers to this will primarily be opinion-based.

Comment: I figured answers would vary, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Is `sql` a custom configuration or created by any plugin?

Comment: it's a custom one.  I think for now I'll just do sql { extendsFrom compile } and be done with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DependencyHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html) can accept lists of dependencies, thus the list can be extracted and stored separately in the build script:

```
ext {
    mysql = ["mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysql_conn_ver}", 
             "other.package:other-artficact-id:${other.version}"]
}

dependencies{
    compile mysql
    sql mysql
}
```